# Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined with socket.io and mocha

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mocha.js, chai

I am beginner to use socket.io with NodeJS and mocha. After usage of socket.io client and server I am getting below error

`Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined` during project build. Below are the files and code details

backend/main.ts

```
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
...

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'))

...

export const io = require('socket.io')(http)
io.listen(http)
io.on('connection', (client: SocketIO.Socket) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('Socket open Connection')
  client.on('disconnect', () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('socket disconnect')
  })
})
...
```

backend/routes/api/index.ts

```
const router = Router()

// Global middleware for all /api routes

router.use('/ping', ping)
router.use('/crm', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, crmSource)
router.use('/app', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, app)
router.use('/app-users', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, ensureIsGlobalTeamMember, appUsers)
router.use('/business', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, ensureIsAdmin, business)
router.use('/app-offers', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, appOffers)
router.use('/app-contracts', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, appContracts)
router.use('/app-order', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, appOrders)
router.use('/app-export', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, appDetailsExport)
router.use('/app-global-settings', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, appGlobalSettings)

if (config.environment === 'local' || config.environment === 'dev') {
  router.use('/translations', translationRoutes)
}

// Non-existent API routes should return 404, not the HTML page
router.use((_req, res) => {
  res.status(404).end()
})

// export default router
module.exports = router
```

backend/routes/api/crmSource/ts

```
const router = Router()
router.get('/', (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => { ... } )
router.get('/source/number/:sourceNumber', (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => { ... } )
...
export default router
```

backend/routes/api/appUsers.ts

```
const router = Router()

router.post(...)
router.delete(...)

export default router
```

All other middleware in the Global middleware router is being written in the same fashion.

When I import io from main.ts for socket communication in the below file
checkout-offer.ts

```
import {io as socketIoConnection} from './main'
...


function checkoutOffer(db, logger, offer, token) {
    socketIoConnection.emit('saveOffer')
    await db.saveCheckoutOffer(offer, logger, token)
    socketIoConnection.emit('offerCheckedOut')
    return db.getCheckedOffer(db, updatedOffer.id)
}
...
```

i get below error in the test build with mocha. The socket implementation without running mocha test runs perfectly fine in the application. But while running the `npm run test` i get this error.

```
> myproject@1.0.0 test /Users/<user>/myproject
> npm-run-all --sequential test:unit lint test:api test:browser


> myproject@1.0.0 test:unit /Users/<user>/myproject
> NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu mocha "test/unit/**/*test.{tsx,ts}"

ERROR myproject: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
        at Function.use (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/myproject/backend/routes/api/index.ts:28:8)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Module.m._compile (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/myproject/backend/main.ts:91:17)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Module.m._compile (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/myproject/backend/finalize-offer.ts:18:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Module.m._compile (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/myproject/backend/routes/api/offers.ts:15:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Module.m._compile (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/myproject/test/unit/i18n-test.ts:8:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Module.m._compile (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at /Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
        at Mocha.run (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:536:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<user>/myproject/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:573:18)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

package.json test script

```
"test": "npm-run-all --sequential test:unit lint test:api test:browser",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx,.js . && stylelint \"**/*.less\" \"**/*.css\"",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx,.js . --fix && stylelint \"**/*.less\" \"**/*.css\" --fix",
    "test:unit": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu mocha \"test/unit/**/*test.{tsx,ts}\"",
    "test:api": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu mocha test/api/**/*.ts",
    "test:browser": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu mocha test/browser/**/*.ts",
```

This is the middleware where it being imported in `backend/routes/api/index.ts` (provided above) global router middleware `router.use('/app-offers', isLoggedIn, ensureAccessToken, appOffers)`

backend/routes/api/appOffers.ts

```
/* imports */

const router = Router()
const upload = multer()

router.post('/offer/:offerId', (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

router.get('/:offerId', (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

router.post('/offer/:offerId/finalize', (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

export const setActiveOfferAsInCrm = (restUrl: string, accessToken: string, logger: Logger) => async (offers: SavedOffer[]): Promise<SavedOffer[]> => {
  ...
}

router.post('/:offerId/activate', (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

router.post('/:offerId/doc-attachment/upload/:type', upload.single('file'), async (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

router.post('/:offerId/doc-attachment/:attachmentId/delete', async (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

router.post('/:offerId/cloning', async (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

router.post('/:offerId/doc-attachment', async (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})


enum AttachmentTypes {
  _Docx = 'docx',
  _Jpg = 'jpg',
  _Pdf = 'pdf',
  _Xlsx = 'xlsx',
  _Csv = 'csv'
}
type DocumentType = AttachmentTypes._Docx | AttachmentTypes._Jpg | AttachmentTypes._Pdf | AttachmentTypes._Xlsx
export const documentTypes: DocumentType[] = [AttachmentTypes._Docx, AttachmentTypes._Jpg, AttachmentTypes._Pdf, AttachmentTypes._Xlsx]

export function getDocumentFilename(documentType: DocumentType) {
  switch (documentType) {
    ...
  }
}

function getEmailAttachmentName(t: TranslationFunction, AttachmentTypes: AttachmentTypes, extension: string): string {
  const prefixAndTranslate = (key: string) => t('contractPdf.' + key)

  switch (AttachmentTypes) {
   ...
  }
}

function getEmailAdditionalAttachmentName(t: TranslationFunction, AttachmentTypesNumber: number, originalName: string): string {
  const prefixAndTranslate = (key: string) => t('contractPdf.' + key)
  return prefixAndTranslate('AttachmentTypes') + ' ' + AttachmentTypesNumber + ' - ' + originalName
}

async function loadAndAttachDocument(logger: Logger,
                                     t: TranslationFunction,
                                     businessId: BusinessId,
                                     language: Language,
                                     documentType: DocumentType): Promise<AttachmentFile | undefined> {
  ...
}

export function getDocumentPath(businessId: BusinessId, language: Language, documentType: DocumentType): string {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'assets', 'AttachmentTypeses', businessId, language, getDocumentFilename(documentType))
}

router.post('/:offerId/email', async (req: ApiRequest, res: Response) => {
  ...
})

export default router
```

Comment: Which line of code does the error occur on?  It's obviously one of the `router.use()` statements, but which one?  It looks like it's probably line 28 in index.ts.  In all your `router.use()` statements, where do all the middleware functions comes from?  You will have to show us that.  If something you're passing to `router.use()` is `undefined`, then you'll have to figure out which route handler is not defined properly.

Comment: Sure @jfriend00. I will post those middleware Routers too. I will take some time to post them.  Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have posted some of the middleware that i have used in global middleware router. All of the other middleware are being similar as per the appUsers.ts fashion.

Comment: So far, you're missing the MOST important clue (the first question I asked you in my original comment).   Which `router.use()` line of your code does the error occur on?   That info is in the stack trace in the error dump (that you posted here).  Then, you need to examine each of the parameters passed to `router.use()` on that line and you will find the problem.  We cannot do this for you.  I'm telling you how you can find the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 i got to know which middleware was undefined. But not getting why? Because even this middleware is being written in the same fashion as others except there are some export constants and export functions and at the end it has ```export default router ```

Comment: Well, if you tell me which middleware it was and show me that entire module so I can see exactly how that is exported and also show the code where it's imported, then I could look at the code and have a chance to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have added code for the appOffers.ts where it is returning undefined in global middleware routes.

Comment: @jfriend00 the issue exactly points the use of ```import {io as socketIoConnection} from './main'``` from the main.ts ```export const io = require('socket.io')(http) ```

Comment: Can't help you until you provide the full information I previously asked for.  You don't tell me which route has the problem.  You don't show where you import that route.

Comment: You also haven't told us which line of code the error occurs on.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your response. I got it resolved from A J A Y's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some refactoring. Maybe, you can shift the multiple export methods from backend/routes/api/appOffers.ts to respective utils and retain export default router as it is.

I had a similar problem long back where export default differently than module.exports.